# PDO expeced array not returning only a boolean of 1 on webpage

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, boolean

I am working to create a content class which will pull all content from the database via a PDO, then run the results through a method which will convert the results into objects, and the loop through the objects, and echo the object to a specific module of the webpage.

**What is expected**

When the class is activated, there will be an instance created via a PDO that will retrieve the needed data from the mysql database. Then this information will echo out and display on the webpage.

**What is happening**

I end up with no errors and the boolean number "1" where content should be. At first I thought this was an sql error. I get the same result "1" if I use print_r($query_result). See my tests below.

**My class code is below**

```
    <?php


    class Content {

    // --- START OF ACTIVE RECORD CODE ---

    public $n_id; 
    public $n_name; 
    public $n_text; 
    public $n_photo; 

    // Instantiating a STATIC Database Connection for the class to use
    static protected $dbconnect;

    static public function database($dbconnect) {
      self::$dbconnect = $dbconnect;
    }
    // constructing arguments

    public function __construct($args=[]) {

      $this->n_id = $args['n_id'] ?? '';
      $this->n_name = $args['n_name'] ?? '';
      $this->n_text = $args['n_text'] ?? '';
      $this->n_photo = $args['n_photo'] ?? '';
    }

    // Multi use method to pass in sql that will execute the PDO only two parameters are bound ID and contentText.
    static public function find_by_sql($sql) {

    // -------------BEGIN PDO-----------

    // preparing PDO by loading sql, calling db connection, and storing in variable $stmt

      $stmt = self::$dbconnect->prepare($sql);
      // Binding Parameters for sql
      $stmt->bindParam(':nid', $n_id,  PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->bindParam(':nall', $n_name,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':ntext', $n_text,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':nphoto', $n_photo,  PDO::PARAM_INT);
      // executing $stmt PDO and storing the result in $stmt
      $query_result = $stmt->execute();
      return $query_result;
      // clearing the PDO after information is stored in $record
      $stmt->closeCursor();


    // ------------END PDO ----------

      // Checking to see if a result exist. If nop result is stored in $stmt, then it will echo "Database query failed."
      if(!$query_result) {
        exit("Query doesn't exist.");
      }
    // -------- BEGIN TURNING RESULTS INTO OBJECTS --------
    $object_array = [];

      // The result $stmt will be stored in the variable $record

      while($record = $query_result->fetchAll()) {

        // Taking $record and passing it to the static method instantiate() - see below. This method will return the $object_array.

        $object_array[] = self::instantiate($record);

    }

        return $object_array;

    // ------------ END TURNING RESULTS INTO OBJECTS --------

    }
    // method to test passing $sql to method find_all_sql();

    static public function find_all(){

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM nmain WHERE nid = :id AND nall = :nall AND ntext = :ntext AND nphoto = :nphoto";
        return self::find_by_sql($sql);

    }

    // --- BEGIN INSTANTIATE METHOD TO CREATE OBJECTS ---

    static protected function instantiate($record) {
      $object = new self;
      // Auto assign values
      foreach($record as $property =>  $value) {
        if(property_exists($object, $property)){
          $object->$property = $value;
        }
      }
      return $object;
      }
    // ----- END INSTANTIATE OF RECORD TO CREATE OBJECTS ---

    // ---END OF ACTIVE RECORD CODE---

    }

    ?>

**On my html webpage:**

        $contents = Content::find_all();
         foreach ((array) $contents as $content) {
       echo $content;
     }
```

**What I have tested**

This is the output I get when I run var_dump($stmt);

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(119) "SELECT * FROM ndb WHERE id = :id AND nall = :nall AND ntext = :ntext AND nphoto = :nphoto" }
```

If I copy the query and paste it in myphpadmin the query will run binding the params.

This is the output if I run var_dump($query_result):

```
 bool(true) if I use print_r($query_result) I get "1"
```

This passes my if(!$query_result) test

If I run var_dump($record) or var_dump($query_result) I get nothing. It seems as if $query_result, because it is a bool, has no array to pass to $record.Therefore, there is nothing to convert to an object.I am at a loss here. Is it my PDO binding?

Comment: It looks like you're returning prematurely from your function. You have `return $query_result;` in your `find_by_sql()` function, but then you have code after your return statement.

Comment: Also, you need to fetch and return a row of data, not a pdo statement. `$row = $query_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); return $row;`

Comment: I am attempting to store the result of the PDO $stmt in the new variable $query_result. If I do not return $query_result, then I end up with Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean. Where should I return from the function?

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing here "while($record = $query_result->fetchAll())" in my loop?

Comment: If I strip the class down to just the pdo, I still get a boolean error.

Comment: I changed my query to $sql = "SELECT * FROM `contentmain`", changed my fetch to "while($record = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))" and it works fine now. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch should be on the statement and not the result of the execute (which is just to say the execute has succeeded or failed), also `fetchAll` will attempt to return all records, what you most likely want is `fetch` to process 1 record at a time.  So you should have something like...

```
while($record = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

You can now remove the earlier `return` which is stopping further processing.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse. The issue is still a boolean return from the PDO "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean"

Comment: Just noticed the `$stmt->closeCursor();` which you shouldn't need normally.  So try commenting that out.

Comment: Still no change.